# how to add search bar in ag grid dropdown

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-validation

without a search bar, I am facing the issue it taking more time to search the required field from the dropdown
please tell me how to add a search bar in the ag-grid dropdown (angular )

Answer (score 0):

You can define per column what type of filter you want to use - in your case you'll want to use 'agTextColumnFilter':

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        field: 'yourfield',
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This is not the solution.